# Having trouble in reducer to get all api data together

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am in middle of setting up redux for managing state for all my api data. I have infinite flatlist that grow with query with offset and limit i pass to api param.

Now issue remain — I am able to get first set of data but never combine data of all api calls. I am sure i am doing something silly out there. 
I am stuck badly here that investing day and night here. Any help will greatly appreciated here.

Reducer:

```
import { RECEIVED_NEWS } from './actions';
export const news = (state = [], action) => {
//console.log('action data is '+JSON.stringify(action));
switch (action.type) {
case RECEIVED_NEWS:
    return [...state, action.apidata];
default:
    return state;
}
};
```

Action:

```
export const RECEIVED_NEWS = 'RECEIVED_NEWS';
export const addNews = apidata => ({
type: RECEIVED_NEWS,
apidata
});
```

Sample api data :  https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cb73c978 or https://pastebin.com/rS8Aj4ex 
Object dir that i print with console http://navgujaratsamay.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Screenshot-2019-02-01-at-5.09.41-PM.png

I am expecting merging all all api calls and i am successfully calling store but every time getting only last call data.

Comment: Try setting state to `action.apidata.news`, so `return [...state, action.apidata.news];`

Comment: Thank you @DragoşPaulMarinescu I can not see this helping. 
I have tried even 
    `return Object.assign({}, state, {
            feed: action.apidata
        })`
No Luck

Comment: Awesome @VaibhavVishal It worked like charm. I had `return [...state, ...action.apidata];` and i can see merged data now. You may not be aware but i had sleepless nights here. Thanks a ton buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
return [...state, ...action.apidata]
```

because action.apidata is a array too, you need to spread it too otherwise it will get nested. If `apidata` was not an array just an object, then no need to spread it.

eg:

```
> let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> let arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
> [...arr1, arr2]  // wrong
< [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]]  // gives a nested array

> [...arr1, ...arr2]  // correct
< [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]  // merges properly

> let num = 10
> [...arr1, num]  // no spreading required when it's not an array
< [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]  // merges properly
```

Comment: The way you explained — simple and bang on!